# How to reduce bootup time of linux?

Tags: boot, linux-kernel

I have a PC with the following configuration:

1- CPU: Cor2Duo

2- Ram: 2 GB

3- 40 GB HDD

I just need serial and network. I don't need Xwindow. I just want write an application to work with serial and network.
I need to boot Ubuntu(or another Linux distribution) less than 10 sec. Is it possible? 
if not, if I replace HDD with a SSD, is that possible to reach such a bootup time?

and one more question: recompiling the kernel configuration, would it be useful?

Comment: First, how much time does your computer take before the OS starts? I've known computers where that bit alone took more than 10s. Ubuntu itself should boot in much less than on this hardware that if you make sure that only the services you need start and perhaps blacklist some slow peripherals that you aren't using. How much time is spent in Linux itself? We need to know how far you are from the goal. Do the basics: run [bootchart](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BootCharting) and post the output.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel initialization is only around some seconds. Most of the boot time is the starting and the initialization of the different demons and system settings. Manipulating the kernel won't help too much.

Some ways to make this faster:

1. As I understand, your software is essentially a daemon. Set up to start it as early as possible - because it requires only rs232 and network, you can do this around the first boot tasks. The details depends on your init software.
2. Go into `/etc/init` (here the the init scripts) and uninstall everything what you can.
3. You can easily uninstall X by an `apt-get --purge remove x11-common` command. But it won't help too much, because X hasn't too many daemons. It would nicer to only disabling your X display manager (this is the daemon which starts the console X server, too).